# Is ApolloQueryResult mutable?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

`ApolloQueryResult` type in `apollo-client` is defined as

```
type ApolloQueryResult<T> = {
  data: T;
  errors?: ReadonlyArray<GraphQLError>;
  loading: boolean;
  networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
  stale: boolean;
};
```

and `query` method comes with following signagture

```
query<T,TVariables>(options: QueryOptions<TVariables>): Promise<ApolloQueryResult<T>>;
```

So as a result we get a `Promise` with `ApolloQueryResult` inside.

So either `ApolloQueryResult` is mutable or `loading` and `stale` properties makes no sense (would always be false).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApolloQueryResult is immutable. Generally if you're using the `query` method, you won't be looking at the `loading` or `stale` properties. Those properties are only there because the type is being reused from Observable queries.

Comment: `loading` is definitely important, its needed whenever you're using a `fetchPolicy` that involves network fetching to a GraphQL server.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for confirming my intuition.